# MySQL Replace Into statement in MYSQLBulkLoader c#class

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a c# program, that uses MYSQlBulkloader to insert data. Now I need to add mysql "Replace Into" statement for the bulkloader object.
I'm unable to find an option to use " Replace Into" mysql statement in this statement.

```
    bl.Local = true;
    bl.TableName = MYSqlTableName;
    bl.FieldTerminator = "\t"; // indicates  Tab limited 
    bl.LineTerminator = "\n";
    bl.FileName = MFFileName;
    bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`ConflictOption`](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkloader/conflictoption/) property:

```cs
bl.ConflictOption = MySqlBulkLoaderConflictOption.Replace;
```

Comment: The solution for the bulkloader replace problem is perfect.But I'm getting a "Data too long Data too long for column  at row 1" error. Do I need to change something else.

Comment: @SaraDob Check that your fields actually are tab-delimited. Check that the columns in the input file line up with the DB columns correctly. Check that the data in the fields isn't too long for the destination columns.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It is the same txt file i used to load the complete data, I'm loading with.When I add this confictoption in the c# class, i get this error.